# Is there a way to write a function that gets an IP Address using HttpServletRequest without passing it as an argument?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm creating a function that doesn't take an HttpServletRequest object as an argument because depending on the session (it could be either through a mobile device or a web browser). If it's a mobile device, it uses the latitude and longitude, or if its from a web browser, I want to be able to grab the IP address. Is there a way to achieve this? Every examples I saw takes an HttpServletRequest as an argument.

This is an example of what I would like to accomplish, **if possible**.

```
public String getLocation(Session session) {
    switch(session.getLocation()) {
        case Mobile:
            System.out.printf("Latitude is %s and Longitude is %s\n", session.getLatitude(), session.getLongitude());
            break;
        case Web:
            HttpServletRequest request;
            String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
            System.out.printf("The IP Adress is %s", ipAddress);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("Error\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `Session`?

Comment: Session is just a made up class that has info about a user's session (name, ID number, is he logged on through a browser or mobile, etc). This is just an example of what I would like to accomplish. @Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

An IP address is a property of a request. Session may correspond to many requests (that comprise that session), and they may come from different IP addresses. So it is not possible to derive a unique IP address from a `Session` in some 'standard' way.

But what you can do is store an IP address from request to its session in a filter. For example, each request could simply write its IP address to the session's attribute, so at any moment you'd have access to the IP address of the last request in that session. Or you could implement some `Accumulator` and store it in your session and put request's IP address to that `Accumulator` which would implement some logic (like choosing 'the most popular' IP address, or do something else). That's up to you.

How to implement the filter:

```
public class RequestIPSavingFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            final String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
            Accumulator accumulator = (Accumulator) request.getSession().getAttribute("accumulator");
            if (accumulator == null) {
                accumulator = new Accumulator();
                request.getSession().setAttribute("accumulator", accumulator);
            }
            accumulator.putIpAddress(ipAddress);
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Later, in your session processing code, you do

```
Accumulator accumulator = (Accumulator) request.getSession().getAttribute("accumulator");
```

and use `accumulator.getBestIpAddress()`